# Ordenamiento externo de datos

Tags: estructuras-de-datos, java-8

Mi problema es el siguiente:

Tengo un archivo.csv en el cual se encuentran almacenados los atributos de un objeto los cuales son: CP,Calle,numero,colonia,destinatario quiero ordenar estos atributos en base al CP con el siguiente codigo:

public class ExternalSort{

```
static int N = 2000000; /** size of the file in disk */
static int M = 100000;  /** max items the memory buffer can hold */

public static void externalSort(String fileName)
{
    String tfile = "temp-file-";
    int[] buffer = new int[M < N ? M : N];

    try
    {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileName);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        int slices = (int) Math.ceil((double) N/M);

        int i, j;
        i = j = 0;
        /** Iterar a través de los elementos del archivo */
        for (i = 0; i < slices; i++)
        {
            /** Leer fragmentos de M-elementos a la vez desde el archivo */
            for (j = 0; j < (M < N ? M : N); j++)
            {
                String t = br.readLine();
                if (t != null)
                    buffer[j] = Integer.parseInt(t.substring(0,4));
                else
                    break;
            }
            /** Sort M elementos */
            Arrays.sort(buffer);

            /** Escriba los números ordenados en el archivo temporal */
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(tfile + Integer.toString(i) + ".txt");
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
            for (int k = 0; k < j; k++)
                pw.println(buffer[k]);

            pw.close();
            fw.close();
        }

        br.close();
        fr.close();

        /** Ahora abra cada archivo y combinelos, luego vuelva a escribirlos en el disco */
        int[] topNums = new int[slices];
        BufferedReader[] brs = new BufferedReader[slices];

        for (i = 0; i < slices; i++)
        {
            brs[i] = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(tfile + Integer.toString(i) + ".txt"));
            String t = brs[i].readLine();
            if (t != null)
                topNums[i] = Integer.parseInt(t);
            else
                topNums[i] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("external-sorted.txt");
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);

        for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            int min = topNums[0];
            int minFile = 0;

            for (j = 0; j < slices; j++)
            {
                if (min > topNums[j])
                {
                    min = topNums[j];
                    minFile = j;
                }
            }

            pw.println(min);
            String t = brs[minFile].readLine();
            if (t != null)
                topNums[minFile] = Integer.parseInt(t);
                else
                topNums[minFile] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }
        for (i = 0; i < slices; i++)
            brs[i].close();

        pw.close();
        fw.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(NullPointerException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } 
}


static String generateInput(int n)
{
    String fileName = "external-sort.txt";
    Random rand = new Random();

    try
    {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fileName);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            pw.println(rand.nextInt(9900) + 100);

        pw.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return fileName;
}
```

Se supone que me tiene que devolver el archivo ordenado en base al CP pero no 
lo hace.

**Como ejemplo tengo los siguientes datos:**

68148,Sur,45,Real Casa Blanca (Residencial),Juan Gabriel Contreras Caceres

68010,Sur,57,Elsa (Fraccionamiento),Tomas Prieto Jurado

68045,Oriente,144,Estrella (Colonia),Jorge Conde Prieto

**Y el archivo ordenado tendría que resultar asi:**

68010,Sur,57,Elsa (Fraccionamiento),Tomas Prieto Jurado

68045,Oriente,144,Estrella (Colonia),Jorge Conde Prieto

68148,Sur,45,Real Casa Blanca (Residencial),Juan Gabriel Contreras Caceres

Comment: Me parece que esto se a tratado con anterioridad.Mira el siguiente enlace, esta muy bien explicado y esta aceptado. [enlace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26448813/how-to-sort-csv-file-by-two-columns-in-java)

Comment: Gracias amigo pero el código de esa respuesta es algo complejo para mi, yo quiero pensar que mi algoritmo que hice para ordenar **n** numeros también funciona para ordenar String pero no encuentro exactamente como adaptarlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

si quieres ordenar una objecto de una clase creada por ti lo puedes realizar asi

implementar la Interfaz Comparable y luego implementar su metodo abstracto compareTo

import java.util.*;

public class StackOverflow implements Comparable{

```
private int codigo ;

public StackOverflow(int codigo)
{
    this.codigo = codigo;
}

public static void main(String[] agrs) 
{
    List<StackOverflow> lista = new ArrayList<>();
    lista.add(new StackOverflow(10));
    lista.add(new StackOverflow(3));
    lista.add(new StackOverflow(20));

    System.out.println(lista);
    Collections.sort(lista);
    System.out.println(lista);

}

public int compareTo(StackOverflow o) 
{
    //orden ascendente
    return this.codigo - o.codigo ;

    //orden descendente
    //return o.codigo - this.codigo;
}

public String toString()
{
    return ""+codigo;
}
```

}

Espero te sirva 
Saludos.

Comment: Te recomiendo que agreges un ejemplo de tu respuesta